# Active Directory users Password reset by using PHP coad

Tags: php

I want to created a portal to reset Active Directory users password by using PHP coad.
I want to create a login page which is login on local admin user and after login by admin users it is showing a console which has enter a Active directory ID (AD ID) whose want to reset your password and enter click reset button. Users password has changed. After reseting of passwords, Password has same for all users just like-Abc@xyz so users is able to change our password by login AD systems.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: Dont do that, because of [Microsoft is dropping PHP support from Windows](https://betanews.com/2020/07/11/microsoft-drops-php-support/)

Comment: Is "PHP coad" a library with poor SEO (I can't find it in Google) or some typo?

Comment: @Luuk Not sure what you mean or how it relates to this question. Active Directory is based on the LDAP network protocol and you can speak to LDAP servers from any operating system. Also, I don't think Microsoft has even been a major player in PHP development—pretty often they didn't even care updating their own extensions like SQLSRV.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález "PHP coad" is surely i typo, i think "PHP code" is meant...

Comment: The question in itself is bad/insecure, because of the "Password has same for all users".  After the change anyone can logon, as long as they have more than 1 username.  Just because of this the question should be 'Closed'.